docker-compose.yml postgres service automatically shutting down
db-1      | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db-1      | This user must also own the server process.
db-1      |
db-1      | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db-1      | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db-1      | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db-1      |
db-1      | Data page checksums are disabled.
db-1      |
db-1      | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db-1      | creating subdirectories ... ok
db-1      | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db-1      | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db-1      | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db-1      | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
db-1      | creating configuration files ... ok
db-1      | running bootstrap script ... ok
db-1      | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db-1      | syncing data to disk ... ok
db-1      |
db-1      | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db-1      | initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db-1      |
db-1      | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db-1      |
db-1      |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db-1      |
db-1      | waiting for server to start....2024-04-29 05:22:32.020 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
db-1      | 2024-04-29 05:22:32.032 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db-1      | 2024-04-29 05:22:32.064 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-04-29 05:22:30 UTC
db-1      | 2024-04-29 05:22:32.090 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db-1      |  done
db-1      | server started
db-1      | CREATE DATABASE
db-1      |
db-1      |
db-1      | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db-1      |
db-1      | waiting for server to shut down....2024-04-29 05:22:32.491 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db-1      | 2024-04-29 05:22:32.511 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db-1      | 2024-04-29 05:22:32.522 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
db-1      | 2024-04-29 05:22:32.537 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
db-1      | 2024-04-29 05:22:32.545 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
db-1      | 2024-04-29 05:22:32.892 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 923 buffers (5.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.055 s, sync=0.236 s, total=0.355 s; sync files=301, longest=0.015 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4257 kB, estimate=4257 kB; lsn=0/1913078, redo lsn=0/1913078
db-1      | 2024-04-29 05:22:32.908 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
db-1      |  done
db-1      | server stopped
db-1      |
db-1      | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

this is my Dockerfile
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk

COPY target/inai-attendance-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]

my docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"
services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "5433:5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - POSTGRES_DB=inai_attendance
    server:
        build: .
        ports:
            - 8081:8080
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            - SPRING_DATA_SOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/inai_attendance
            - SPRING_DATA_SOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
            - SPRING_DATA_SOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres

I tried a lot of things, but couldn't solve it

It's normal that the container starts the database in 'socket only' mode to run the initialization scripts. Then it shuts the database down and starts it in 'normal' mode where it listens for network connections. You should see more log messages where it starts the database again.

Did you try different image versions? E.g. postgres:14.1-alpine ?
